# Why is SimpleJpaRepository injected as a default CrudRepository?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

In Spring Boot (Spring Data) project a custom repository (i.e. `UserRepository`) extends `CrudRepository` provided by Spring. At runtime I see that the actual implementation that is injected is `SimpleJpaRepository`.

Since I do not specify any classes to inject I'd like to better understand how does Spring know to inject this particular class?

I understand that by default Spring autowires by type, but `SimpleJpaRepository` is not the only implementation of `CrudRepository`, there are others, such as `QuerydslJpaRepository`.

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleJpaRepository` is the default implementation of `CrudRepository`. That's the reason it is injected. Please refer [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html)

Comment: I know that SimpleJpaRepository is default implementation of CrudRepository, I want to understand how does Spring know to inject this particular class. Does Spring create a bean of SimpleJpaRepository and inject it for me, where does it happen?